# Integration forum framework on own site

Tags: php, database, forum

I want to integrate some forum on my own site, but the problem is that i have to find solution to merge or connect my users table with forum framework users table, i mean user in my site can create forum and the other users can us it. i did research for find good forum framework which has good api for integration, but can't find, i tried to use phpBB open source forum, but all integration part for this forum, only about login user or something like that.
If anyone did this kind of work please help me, which forum tool is best for this situation and how can i made this think.

Comment: I have worked with phpbb. What features of the forum you want in your site? If you can be more specific, i can help you.

Comment: On another note, most forums provide api. But the best bet is smf if you don't want to dig much deeper. It comes with a SSI file which contains most functions of the forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vanilla Forums works really good for this. Vanilla 2 features Single sign on and you can create your own Plugin for your website: http://vanillaforums.org/docs/singlesignon